# How to know/contact a community which hold an API (ODBC API)

Tags: odbc, api, standards

I am currently working with the `unix-odbc` API to create my own ODBC driver.

I found on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Database_Connectivity) that ODBC is a standard and is implemented by communities.

> In computing, Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) is a standard application programming interface (API) for accessing database management systems (DBMS).

So there also is a community that handle the standard. But I can't find this standard.

**Question:** Where is this standard? And can a community decide to not implement a function in their API?

Answer (score 0):

The ODBC standard is maintained by Microsoft and published on their website as a set of articles under [ODBC Programmer's Reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/odbc-programmer-s-reference?view=sql-server-2017). Everyone is free to write their own ODBC drivers according to the standard *ODBC API*.

*unixODBC* is merely one of the many ODBC driver managers, whereas every ODBC driver should work with every driver manager. If your question is specific to *unixODBC* (which I rather doubt) then you may contact its maintainer.

A good way to start writing an ODBC driver is to study existing open-source drivers and ask help from their developers, but be very polite and take no umbrage if they refuse to consult you, especially on something that is readily available in existing documentation. You ought to try very hard to solve every problem yourself before asking the help of others. By this sign they will know their efforts won't be wasted.

Here is a couple of open-source ODBC drivers:

1. [Oracle](https://peter.fedorapeople.org/oracle_unixodbc_driver.html),
2. [MySQL](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-odbc).